# How to adjust webview inside a parent scrollview?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uiwebview, uiscrollview

I have a ScrollView within which I am adding TextViews, ImageViews and a UIWebView. I am able to dynamically adjust the height of all these views except the UIWebView.

I have turned off the scrolling of the UIWebView, and want to resize the WebView according to its content. And at the same time resize the scrollview according to the resized WebView.

The scrollview should contain the resized WebView. I think there is much discussion about and around this but I haven't been able to reach a concrete solution. So any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

here is what you can try

After you have loaded content in the UIWebView you can use it's `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` method to ask the html document for its height. This is a little tricky but should work.

You can do something like this:

```
NSInteger height = [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
    @"document.body.scrollHeight"] integerValue];
```

The `scrollheight` mught not be the best. You have a couple of options. Experiment with the document properties mentioned in http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/get-document-height-cross-browser/

after that u can resize you `scrollview` to the content,

this is the only method seems working, till now. Good- luck